# Ruby on Rails SOLR facets between 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, facet

In my classifieds app , my "main" model is `Classifieds` but i have also implemented categorization so `Categories has_many :classifieds`

Also i have implemented my `Categories` with `awesome_nested_set`

And i have Solr search too!

In my sites `Classifieds - index.html.erb` i render the Classifieds and if search is used i render the corresponding Classifieds.

Now i have implemented a navbar which uses the `Category` model for navigation.
The navbar shows the Category.roots and the descendants of each root with a dropdown. This leads to the `Category - show.html.erb` ,where `Classifieds` are shown according to the `Category` they are in!

So the question is here:
In my `Classifieds - index.html.erb` i have successfully implemented Solr facets , which are used as filters but this only works when the user either Searches or just filters in the initial index! So in simple words when he interacts with the `Classifieds Controller`.

How can i preserve the facet functionality when the user uses the navbar , which means he then interacts with the `Category controller`

Models:

```
class Classified < ApplicationRecord


    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category


    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :classified

    has_many :favorite_classifieds, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :favorited_by , through: :favorite_classifieds , source: :user #for the favorite_by to work :source is needed

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos


    searchable do 
        text :title, :boost => 5
        text :model , :created_month , :make , :make_country , :condition ,:treecat,:cat,:price #TO BE CHANGED TO CURRENCY FORMAT

        time :created_at

        string :treecat
        string :price #TO BE CHANGED TO CURRENCY FORMAT
        string :created_month   
        string :cat
        string :make_country
        string :condition
        string :make    
        string :model
    end

    def cat 
        category.root.name
    end

    def treecat
        category.name unless category.name == category.root.name
    end

    def created_month 
        created_at.strftime("%B")
    end    
end



class Category < ApplicationRecord

    acts_as_nested_set
    has_many :classifieds
end




 Classifieds controller index action 
        def index

            @search = Classified.search do 
                paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 10)
                order_by(:created_at , :desc)
                fulltext params[:search]
                with(:created_at)

                active_model = with(:model ,params[:model]) if params[:model].present?

                active_make = with(:make , params[:make]) if params[:make].present?

                active_make_country = with(:make_country , params[:make_country]) if params[:make_country].present?

                active_condition = with(:condition,params[:condition]) if params[:condition].present?

                active_category = with(:cat,params[:cat]) if params[:cat].present?

                active_subcategory = with(:treecat,params[:treecat]) if params[:treecat].present?

                facet(:model)                   
                facet(:make)        
                facet(:make_country)   
                facet(:condition)           
                facet(:cat , exclude: active_subcategory)               
                facet(:treecat)                 
            end
            @classifieds = @search.results
end
```

Categories controller show action

```
def show            
    @category = Category.find_by_id(params[:id])    
end
```

Classifieds - index.html.erb

```
<div class="indexbox">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 visible-lg">
        <div class="facets">            


            <h6>Μάρκα</h6>
            <ul class="facetlist">
                <% for row in @search.facet(:make).rows %>
                <li>
                    <% if params[:make].blank? %>
                    <%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:make => row.value).permit!) %> <small class="rowcount"><%= row.count %></small>
                    <% else %>
                    <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :make => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

            <h6>Χώρα Κατασκευής</h6>
            <ul class="facetlist">
                <% for row in @search.facet(:make_country).rows %>
                <li>
                    <% if params[:make_country].blank? %>
                    <%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:make_country => row.value).permit!) %> <small class="rowcount"><%= row.count %></small>
                    <% else %>
                    <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :make_country => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

            <h6>Κατάσταση</h6>
            <ul class="facetlist">
                <% for row in @search.facet(:condition).rows %>
                <li>
                    <% if params[:condition].blank? %>
                    <%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:condition => row.value).permit!) %> <small class="rowcount"><%= row.count %></small>
                    <% else %>
                    <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :condition => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

            <h6>Κατηγορία</h6>
            <ul class="facetlist">
                <% for row in @search.facet(:cat).rows %>
                <li>
                    <% if params[:cat].blank? %>
                    <%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:cat => row.value).permit!) %> <small class="rowcount"><%= row.count %></small>
                    <% else %>
                    <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :cat => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

            <h6>Κατηγορία</h6>
            <ul class="facetlist">
                <% for row in @search.facet(:treecat).rows %>
                <li>
                    <% if params[:treecat].blank? %>
                    <%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:treecat => row.value).permit!) %> <small class="rowcount"><%= row.count %></small>
                    <% else %>
                    <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :treecat => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>




    <% @classifieds.each do |f| %>
        <% if !f.sold %>

            <div class="center-div" id="index">

                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <div class="listingoptions">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <p><%= link_to "", new_classified_message_path(:recipient_id => f.user_id , :classified_id => f.id), :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" , :style => "color:#EFCE7B" %></p>

                                <%if current_user.favorite_classifieds.collect(&:classified_id).include?(f.id) %>

                                    <p><%= link_to "", favorite_classified_path(f, type: "unfavorite") , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart" , :style => "color:#FF0000", method: :put %></p>

                                <%else%>

                                    <p><%= link_to "", favorite_classified_path(f, type: "favorite") , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" , :style => "color:#000000", method: :put %></p>

                                <%end%>

                                <p><%= link_to "", editlisting_path(f) , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-flag"  , :style => "color:#EB573B" %></p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <%= link_to classified_path(f) , :class => "link" do %>
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="mediabox">

                            <div class="media-left" href="#">


                                <!-- <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="Generic placeholder image">-->
                                <% if f.photos.first %>
                                    <%= image_tag f.photos.first.image.url , :class => "media-object"%>

                                <%end%>

                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h5 class="media-heading"> <%= f.title %></h5>
                                <small><%= f.created_month %></small>
                                <% if f.category.parent_id? %>
                                    <small><%= f.category.root.name %></small>
                                <%end%>
                                <small><%= f.category.name %></small>
                                <div class="price ">                    
                                    <h5><%= f.price %> </h5>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>



        <%end%>
    <%end%>
    <%end%>

    <div class="center-div">
        <div class="digg_pagination">
            <%= will_paginate @classifieds , :previous_label => '<', :next_label => '>' %>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

Categories show.html.erb

```
<div class="indexbox">
    <div class="center-div" id="index">

        <div class="categorytitle">
            <h4>
                <%= @category.root.name %>
                <% unless @category.name == @category.root.name %>
                <span> >> </span><%= @category.name %>

            </h4>
            <%end%>
        </div>
    </div>

    <% @category.self_and_descendants.each do |desc| %>
        <% desc.classifieds.each do |f|%>

            <% if !f.sold %>

                <div class="center-div" id="index">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <div class="listingoptions">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <p><%= link_to "", new_classified_message_path(:recipient_id => f.user_id , :classified_id => f.id), :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" , :style => "color:#EFCE7B" %></p>

                                    <%if current_user.favorite_classifieds.collect(&:classified_id).include?(f.id) %>

                                        <p><%= link_to "", favorite_classified_path(f, type: "unfavorite") , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart" , :style => "color:#FF0000", method: :put %></p>

                                    <%else%>

                                        <p><%= link_to "", favorite_classified_path(f, type: "favorite") , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" , :style => "color:#000000", method: :put %></p>

                                    <%end%>

                                    <p><%= link_to "", editlisting_path(f) , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-flag"  , :style => "color:#EB573B" %></p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <%= link_to classified_path(f) , :class => "link" do %>
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="mediabox">

                                <div class="media-left" href="#">


                                    <!-- <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="Generic placeholder image">-->
                                    <% if f.photos.first %>
                                        <%= image_tag f.photos.first.image.url , :class => "media-object"%>

                                    <%end%>

                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h5 class="media-heading"> <%= f.title %></h5>
                                    <small><%= f.created_month %></small>

                                    <% if f.category.parent_id? %>
                                        <small><%= f.category.root.name %></small>
                                    <%end%>

                                    <small><%= f.category.name %></small>
                                    <div class="price ">                    
                                        <h5><%= f.price %> </h5>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>



            <%end%>
            <%end%>
        <%end%>

    <%end%>
</div>
```

im a noob , i know there's stuff wrong with my indentation in html , sorry for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i did it by nesting routes and taking some fields from the categories model.

```
    resources :categories do
      resources :classifieds do 
      end
    end
```

Category model:

```
 def nested_classifieds
    Classified.where(category_id: self_and_descendants.select(:id))
end

def nested_categories
    self_and_descendants    
end
```

Classifieds controller

```
def index
    if @category.present? 
      @classifieds = @category.nested_classifieds 
      nested_categories = []
      @category.nested_categories.each do |f|
        nested_categories << f.id
      end

      @search = Sunspot.search(Classified ) do 
        paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 10)
        order_by(:created_at , :desc)
        fulltext params[:search]    
        with(:categoryid,nested_categories)
        active_model = with(:model ,params[:model]) if params[:model].present?      
        active_make = with(:make , params[:make]) if params[:make].present?     
        active_make_country = with(:make_country , params[:make_country]) if params[:make_country].present?     
        active_condition = with(:condition,params[:condition]) if params[:condition].present?
        active_category = with(:cat,params[:cat]) if params[:cat].present?
        active_subcategory = with(:treecat,params[:treecat]) if params[:treecat].present?
        active_pricerange = with(:price, params[:price]) if params[:price].present?

        fulltext params[:prc]
        facet :price
        with(:price).less_than(1000)

        facet(:model) 
        #facet(:model , exclude: active_condition)      
        facet(:make)      
        facet(:make_country)    
        facet(:condition)   
        facet(:cat)   
        facet(:treecat)     
      end
      @classifieds = @search.results  
        else
          #redirect_to '/'
          #@classified=@search.results
          search
    end
  end
```